# "Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying

Tags: solidity, truffle, migration, voting

I do not understand why this is happening, I have tried many solutions, but still without effect.
Updating the truffle version did not help.

`truffle migrate --reset`

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================
- Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***st from solc-bin. Attempt #1

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.
```

Migrations.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

Comment: What solidity version are you using in your contracts? To which chain are you migrating/deploying? Maybe you get an invalid opcode because of PUSH0 introduced by solidity 0.8.20

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading solc from 0.8.20 to 0.8.13 resolved the problem for me.

I got to that version by downloading the metacoin truffle box, verifying that migration works and then getting the version of solc from the truffle-config.js of the project.

It is worth doing the same, rather than using the specific solc version that resolved this for me at this point in time, as Truffle will probably update the metacoin box eventually to keep up with the rest of their tools and this number will get out of date.

Downloading the metacoin truffle box is as easy as this:

```bash
truffle unbox metacoin [PATH/TO/DIRECTORY]
```